# conditional joint density for uniform random variables

Tags: probability

Let U1, U2 be independent random variables both uniformly distributed on [0, 1], and
set
M = max(U1, U2) and
N = min(U1, U2).

Find the conditional joint density of (U1, U2) given M ≤ 1/2

I know that the joint density of (U1, U2) is 1 since it's a square.  But given the condition M, visually it's like restricting the U's to a square 1/4 the size.  So conditional joint density of (U1, U2) when M = 1/2 should be 4.  But I'm not sure how to account for M less than or equal to 4.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $M \le 1/2$ is the same as saying $U_1 \le 1/2$ and $U_2 \le 1/2$. Now, by independence of $U_1$ and $U_2$, we have the following:
$$
P(U_1 \le u_1, U_2 \le u_2 \mid M \le 1/2)
=
P(U_1 \le u_1, U_2 \le u_2, \mid U_1 \le 1/2, U_2 \le 1/2)
\\
=
P(U_1 \le u_1 \mid U_1 \le 1/2) P(U_2 \le u_2 \mid U_2 \le 1/2).
$$
Now, for $U \sim \text{Unif}[0,1]$, for $u \le u'$,
$$ P(U \le u \mid U \le u') = P(U \le u)/P(U \le u') = u / u'. $$
This is because $U \le u$ implies $U \le u'$. Hence, in summary,
$$
P(U_1 \le u_1, U_2 \le u_2 \mid M \le 1/2)
=
(u_1/\tfrac12) \cdot (u_2/\tfrac12)
= 4 u_1 u_2.
$$
This is, of course, only valid for $u_1,u_2 \in [0,\tfrac12]$.

Comment: So the joint conditional density is 4?  Since when we take the derivative of P in terms of U_1, and U_2?

Comment: Yeah, exactly :)

Comment: Has that explained it for you? :)

Comment: Yes!  Sorry for the late response and thanks!